# How to create multiple shortcuts that will open different forms

Tags: c#, winforms

How can you create another executable or Shortcut APP that will open a Form once you start it? In the debug directory, there is the main EXE which will start your Windows Form or your main form, but I have two forms let's say `Start_Form` and `Main_Form`. I want to create a shortcut app for `Start_Form` so it will call once the Windows Start and call the `Main_Form` by double clicking the main EXE found in Debug directory?

Comment: What about `Process.Start()`? More about this on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=start%20a%20process%20c%23&oq=start%20a%20process%20c%23)

Comment: @Adriano Repetti - Thanks! This will only call a file/program to start? But what about the shortcut app that will open the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an argument to your application. Then, depending on that argument, you can show the desired form.

In your Program class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Double clicked on executable file
    if (args == null || args.Length == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]))
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    // Launched from Windows startup
    else if (args[0] == "startup")
    {
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
    // Unrecognized startup parameter
    else
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...);
}
```

And the command line for Windows startup in the registry:

```
"C:\Path\To\Your\Executable.exe" "startup"
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. May i ask, what do you mean by the String `ExpectedValue`?

Comment: That's just a value that you send to your application to specify the behavior you want. It could be anything, this is just an example.

Comment: I understand, thank you, But i don't know how can i tell which form to start. I want the `form1` to start on `Windows Start` and start the `form2` on double clicking the application.

Comment: I am thinking, maybe i can have an integer variable with the default value is 0 then it means it is the first time that the application is started then call the `form1` and make it the value to 1 so that the next time the application started the value is 1 then start the `form2`. e.g. `
int x = 0 
if(x==0){ 

//start form1 

x=1;

}else if(x == 1){ 

//start form2

}`

this is assuming i already add the application in the registry so it will start at `windows start`. I just found the way of starting the application on windows start by adding it into registry programmatically.

Comment: If you double click on the executable file, there won't be any argument. Then, when you start it from startup, you can specify an argument. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much, I'll try this, I'll update you if it works.

Comment: Oops. I got an exception error. `System.IndexOutOfRangeException {"Index was outside the bounds of the array"}`

Comment: I initialize the `args` with ` args = new string[1];` and the exception is gone. the condition is works but the `command line for Windows startup in the registry` is not working, i tried it with `cmd` just to test, but the `"startup"` argument is not working. i tried to `MessageBox.Show(args[0])` and the message box was blank.

Comment: @beliezier It is normal that if you initialize the args array, it will not contain the startup argument. I updated my answer to check the array length (`args.Length == 0`).

Comment: HAHA. Awesome!!! It's working now!!! Thank you very much @PhilDulac!!! Thank you for effort, I really appreciated!!!